# Fram Origin UITabBarController located at the top of the screen programmatically not responding

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to place a UITabBar at the top of the screen in my App below the UINavigationBar. I have the UITabBar positioned correctly but the view in which the tab's content is to be show is being set to the same origin as the TabBar. The code I am using is as follows:

```
tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
            tabC.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);

NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[[UIViewController alloc] init], [[HomeTabViewController alloc] init], nil];
tabC.viewControllers = arr;

[tabC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// CGRect viewFrame = tabC.view.frame;
// viewFrame.origin.y = 40;
// tabC.view.frame = viewFrame;

[_topLayer addSubview:tabC.view];
```

If I try to use the code in the comments to try and change the origin then the whole thing moves down as can be seen in the images below:

Without the commented code:
[image]

With the commented code changing the origin:

[image]

How can I change the Y-axis origin for the View part of a UITabBarController?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting frame using below code?

`tabC.inputView.frame = viewFrame;`